# How can I secure data on record level?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I don't have much experience with Strongloop but maybe someone can put me in the right direction.

In my model I have information of Clients. The Client must have access to their own record but not to the record of other Clients. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strongloop ACL can be easily defined in model JSON definition:

```
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "property": "findById"
    }
]
```

The ACL definition denies everyone to access the model, and allow the owner to read it.

Please note that there must be a model column `userId` to get the buit-in `$owner` principal id work.

ACL definition document: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-ACLs

Official example project for advanced ACL control: 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control

Comment: Thank you Peter, this is very helpful! Do you also know how I can give people access to a set of records in my model based on a Role that I created? Do I need a special column instead of the column "userId" also in this case?

Comment: You can use `Role` and `RoleMapping` to group users: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+and+using+roles